# how to broadcast a PXE server like Trinity Rescue Kit

Tags: networking, multi-boot, dhcp, bootloader, pxe

I would like to set up a portable PXE server for diagnostic purposes.  The issue is that I won't always have access to the DHCP server, or the router itself (sometimes a home router) doesn't have an easily accessible place to set the servername/file for broadcast.

I know that [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org) is able to broadcast its PXE server without its own DHCP server.  Can anyone point me in the direction to set this up on my own (without Trinity)?

Thanks.

Comment: From: http://trinityhome.org/Home/Print_Collate.php?collate_pages=37,182,183,184,185,186,38,54,55,56,57,39,40,42,128,178,45,46,50,47,49,51,52,48,53,179,180,189,43,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,75,181,76,33#DJQBVW3TV8F9F6T9P2QZJ9WFCCVH0HU3SA5CWYWHX2G2Z It says: 1. Prerequisites -A decent configurable dhcp server.  Are you sure about that functionality?

Comment: I understand that, but if you just boot into PXE mode on the trinity disc, it's not asking you to reconfigure any DHCP servers.  I found the script that turns on PXE mode...I just need to play with it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're interested in the information from this page:
http://trinityhome.org/Home/blog_comments.php?blog_id=228

In brief, I think you need to setup a proxy dhcp server.  When the existing DHCP server doesn't know how to handle the PXE requests, the PXE client will broadcast for a proxy DHCP server which will be able to provide the address of a TFTP server and bootfilename.

Comment: << When the existing DHCP server doesn't know how to handle the PXE requests, the PXE client will broadcast for a proxy DHCP server >>
This is not how things really are...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but [this](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=996) post may help you.